# Diagnosing Unresponsive Windows Service

Tags: windows-server-2008, .net, windows-service

I have seen this happen on occasion on our Windows 2008 servers running in AWS EC2 where we have Windows Service which becomes unresponsive. I am not able to find anything in the event logs, or a crash dump. Any ideas, or advice on how to go about diagnosing the root cause of these failures? I have access to the C# source code of the services, but they are not logging any exceptions.

Comment: How do you **know** the services are unresponsive? If you have additional information on why you think the services are unresponsive, could you post that information in your question?

Comment: I know that the service is unresponsive because incoming requests will time out. When I go to the services administrator, the service shows as "Running", however I am unable to restart, or stop the service. I have to actually kill the process in order to restart it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to involve the AWS Developer Forums by posting your issue or by contacting AWS Support. I can give you a few basic suggestions.

## Outdated drivers

There is a post where a user had a issue with a dump file he was unable to understand and he was recommended to list third party drivers that seem to have led to the instance crashing in this post [EC2 instance crashing/dumping](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=407787).

The command `pnputi -e` lists all third-party drivers and maybe this is your issue too.

> Pnputil.exe is a command line utility that you can use to manage the driver store. You can use Pnputil to add driver packages, remove driver packages, and list driver packages that are in the store.

(Microsoft TechNet)

[PNPutil.exe Webpage](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff800798(v=ws.10).aspx)

The post then goes on to mention that there were possibly outdated drivers installed, which would have to be updated.

## Modify Source Code

Seeing as you have the C# source code for the service, you could go ahead and modify the code to create entries in a log file at certain points in the code. Adding a timestamp to the output will help pinpoint your issue.

## Resources

Could the service be consuming to much resources on the AWS instance? See if the service is consuming to much memory or processor time. This could result in the service becoming unresponsive.

## Contact AWS Support

Post your issue in the Sub-Forum that best matches your issue in the [Discussion Forums > Category : Amazon Web Services](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/category.jspa?categoryID=3)

Without further details, it's hard to provide you with a solution on how you could go about fixing your problem. You have to have some data to go from to produce a solution.